# How to connect Azure Multi-Instance Container to Azure Virtual Network

Tags: azure, docker-compose, azure-virtual-network, docker-network, azure-container-instances

**Situation :**
I have created a azure resource.
which has a container registry, virtual network with firewall.

**Problem :**
While creating a single container instance you can specify the virtual network, so that the firewall rules, public static ip and all networking settings gets attached to the container.
But, while deploying multi container instance its done only using command with docker compose on azure context.

**Question :**
I would like to know how to link the multi container instance to the virtual network ?

Comment: How are you deploying this? If it's with an ARM template, could you share it?

Comment: @joelforsyth I am deploying the multi container instance via docker compose file keeping docker context as azure

Comment: **Hey @!, I did reproduce this issue and the solution worked for me; do let me know if it solved your problem else share more details so I can troubleshoot?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**To deploy a multi-container group with the az container create command in the Azure CLI, you must specify the container group configuration in a YAML file. Then pass the YAML file as a parameter to the command.**

This YAML file defines a container group named "`myContainerGroup`" with two containers, a privte IP address, and two exposed ports. The containers are deployed from public Microsoft images. The first container in the group runs an internet-facing web application. The second container, the sidecar, periodically makes HTTP requests to the web application running in the first container via the container group's local network.

***You need to require subnet delegate permissions ie `Microsoft.ContainerInstance/containerGroups`. in your existing Vnet's Subnet***

[image]

**yaml code**

```
apiVersion: '2021-07-01'
location: westus2
name: myContainerGroup
properties:
  containers:
  - name: aci-tutorial-app
    properties:
      image: mcr.microsoft.com/azuredocs/aci-helloworld:latest
      resources:
        requests:
          cpu: 1
          memoryInGb: 1.5
      ports:
      - port: 80
      - port: 8080
  - name: aci-tutorial-sidecar
    properties:
      image: mcr.microsoft.com/azuredocs/aci-tutorial-sidecar
      resources:
        requests:
          cpu: 1
          memoryInGb: 1.5
  osType: Linux
  ipAddress:
    type: Private
    ports:
    - protocol: tcp
      port: 80
    - protocol: tcp
      port: 8080
  restartPolicy: Always
  subnetIds:
    - id: /subscriptions/b83c1XXXXXX-b5ba-2XXXX74c23f/resourceGroups/v-XX-XXX/providers/Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks/Vnet1/subnets/default
      name: default
tags: {exampleTag: tutorial}
type: Microsoft.ContainerInstance/containerGroups
```

[image]

[image]

**Reference** :[*Tutorial: Deploy a multi-container group using a YAML file*](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/container-instances/container-instances-multi-container-yaml#:%7E:text=To%20deploy%20a%20multi%2Dcontainer,a%20parameter%20to%20the%20command.)